# How to find if there is a pivot table used in an Eloquent scope method?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Currently I have 3 tables

- users

  - id, name
- discount

  - id, name, *active*
- discount_user

  - discount_id, user_id, start, end

I need to find all the active discounts for a current user which are currently running based on the `start` and the
`end` dates held on the pivot table.

I was hoping to be able to build a `scopeActive` method on the discount table to narrow down active discounts for the
current user, but I only want the date range to be added if I'm coming from the user table to find the discounts:

```php
$discounts = User::find(1)->discounts()->active()->get(); // within date range
$active = Discount::active()->get(); // without date range check
```

On the user table I've extended the relations to have an 'activeDiscounts' relation which works using:

```php
public function activeDiscounts() {
    return $this->discounts()
            ->where('active', true)
            ->wherePivot('start', '>=', Carbon::now())
            ->wherePivot('end', '<=', Carbon::now());
}
```

Though this works, I don't think it's really best practice and would prefer to be able to use a scope on the discount.

Is there any way I can tell if I'm coming from the user table or through a pivot on the scope query? Also, if so, would I be
able to see the User ID so I can use it in the pivot query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer on your question: You could use arguments in scope, e.g:

```
$discounts = User::find(1)->discounts()->active(true)->get(); // within date range
$active = Discount::active()->get();
```

Scope:

```
public function scopeActive($query, $withDates = false) {
    return $query
        ->where('active', true)
        ->when($withDates, function($query){
            $query
                ->wherePivot('start', '>=', Carbon::now())
                ->wherePivot('end', '<=', Carbon::now());
        });
}
```

But I think that it is not better than your solution.

Also, you could use 2 different scopes.

Comment: I thought something like this too, but pushing in the user id itself so the scope can filter on the dates for that specific user. I'm trying to avoid having to send the extra info each time though

Comment: Not really what I was after but what I ended up having to do in the end!